# C# question on a method signature of a class

Tags: c#

While reading a document, I see an example of a class method such as the following. **Question**: What is the keyword `state` here for? From the context of the document or from online search I could not find anything related to this type of `class method signature`:

```
Public state void myMethod<T>(T obj)
where T : myClass
{
...
}
```

Comment: me neither, there´s no `state`-keyword I´m aware of.

Comment: Did the document perhaps say **static**? _Perhaps show us a screenshot - since the word `Public` is wrong with that casing as well._

Comment: @mjwills No, I double checked, it does say `state`. But, I think your guess is write. It's probably a typo in the document.

Comment: making this question completely un-answerable unless you post the source for this code.